# Node.js: Get client's IP

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

req.connection.remoteAddress, req.headers['x-forwarded-for'], req.ip, req.ips, what does it all mean?

Is there a straight forward way to simply get the IP address of the client/user-agent making the request to my site in Node.js/Express? I'm not understanding all the proxy stuff or what all the differences between all the properties of the req object. Also, I don't understand what the 'trust proxy' option is for Express.

Could someone give me a straight forward explanation to what the difference is between all of these properties, and answer how I can just simply get the client's IP?

Comment: How about using **[node-ipware](https://github.com/un33k/node-ipware)** as per the explanation **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26310355/458879)**.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`req.ip` is the straightforward way to get the client's IP address in Express. You can see the logic it uses (which involves grabbing the first item from the array of proxy addresses `req.ips`, where that array is constructed from the `x-forwarded-for` headers) [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L285-L287).

Comment: Could you describe what x-forwarded-for is?

Comment: Each proxy in front of your server adds the x-forwarded-for header. Lots more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 21):

```
// Get client IP address from request object ----------------------
getClientAddress = function (req) {
        return (req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0] 
        || req.connection.remoteAddress;
};
```

Comment: And what does `req` object holds, I mean what shall we be providing there?

Comment: Note that `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` is easily manipulated at the PC unless you have placed your Node.JS server behind a trusted and properly configured proxy server. You should first check `req.connection.remoteAddress` against a list of known trustable proxy servers before respecting `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`.

Comment: Appreciate the OR and split additions. This is good if you have your app behind both a load balancer and/or a caching layer.

Comment: its returning `::ffff:127.0.0.1` for the first hit and for every later hit it returns `::1`. Both are not the proper public IPs and not able to fetch location out of them. Help me resolve this. Thanking You!

Comment: For 2021, for node.js without express, its still answer! Upload that to hosting to make it work correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As other's have noted, due to the use potential use of proxies, you really should use `req.ip` and NOT use the X-Forwarded-For header like so many people are recommending. As long as you properly configure a proxy as a trusted proxy, `req.ip` will always return the end-user's IP address.

e.g. If you had a proxy that was connecting from 8.8.8.8, you'd do:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', '8.8.8.8');
```

Since you trust the proxy, this would now make it so what is passed in the X-Forwarded-For header will be stored in `req.ip`, but ONLY if it originates from one of the trusted proxies.

More on trust proxy [can be found here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html).

Now, as others have noted in the comments; especially when developing locally you may get the `ip` in the format of "::ffff:127.0.0.1".

To always get the IPv4 Address I have:

```
getClientAddress = function (req) {
    return req.ip.split(":").pop();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

very simple

```
function getClientIP(req){
    return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have placed `app.enable('trust proxy');` in my server.ts file right after my following code `import { serverApi, createTodoApi } from './backend/api'; app.get('/data.json', serverApi); app.use('/api', createTodoApi());` and accessing the variables `req.ip` in my backend/api.ts file. Where its returning `::ffff:127.0.0.1`, which is not a valid ip address to fetch the location out of it. Waiting for your response. Thanks!

Comment: I also had the `ffff` initially when tested locally. While it's easy to parse, I opted to set the server to listen only to IPv4 (I have a proxy anyway), based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170565/5362795) and that gives me a clean IPv4 on `remoteAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the client IP is pretty straightforward:

```
 var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
     console.log(ip);
```

Comment: Note that `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` is easily manipulated at the PC unless you have placed your Node.JS server behind a trusted and properly configured proxy server. You should first check `req.connection.remoteAddress` against a list of known trustable proxy servers before respecting `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`. If there are multiple proxies involved, then `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` may contain a comma separated list.