# Get the IP address from request url

Tags: node.js, nginx, httprequest

How to get the IP address from HTTP request url or the client IP from where my node code is running.

```
http://127.0.0.1:1000/samp/
```

The client IP can be an nginx IP or public IP. Any help on this will be really helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at these questions [How can I get the user's IP address using Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-using-node-js), [Node.js: Get client's IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266329/node-js-get-clients-ip)

Comment: One second, you want the **client IP**, or the **current machine IP**?

Comment: ping the domain you will see its IP

Comment: @The Scrum Meister I need the client IP. I used request.connection.remoteAddress and request.headers['X-Forwarded-For'], but Im not getting the exact IP.

Comment: Is it possible to get the IP from the request url using connect?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the *client* ip, you'll need to first decide if you trust "X-Forwarded-For" headers (that is: you are behind a reverse proxy that you yourself set up and which you trust, or you trust the proxies along the way).

If so, then get the ip in `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` (this could potentially be a list).

If not, then `req.connection.remoteAddress` is the answer.

Comment: Im using connect. I tried req.ip which is returning me output undefined

Comment: req.ip is only in express. Use what I wrote above.

Comment: How can I get the nginx ip if my code is running behind reverse proxy?

Comment: Modern Nginx gives you a slightly different `Forwarded` header. See https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.send(req.connection.remoteAddress);
    });
```