# Is Node/Express redefining request.ip?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a legit business need to test the way our server works using a fake IP address. We use `request.ip` in a bunch of different places and I'd rather not have to replace every single instance of "request.ip" with the fake IP address, so I figured I would just redefine it at the application's entrypoint (the start of the callback chain). However, I ran into some unexpected behavior when `request.ip` apparently changed itself back to "127.0.0.1"!

This is the (CoffeeScript) code I inserted into the "handle" method:

```
spanishIp ='37.35.128.128'
request.ip = spanishIp
console.log "ip: #{request.ip} / #{spanishIp}"
```

Resulting in the following log:

```
ip: 127.0.0.1 / 37.35.128.128
```

Evidently, `request.ip` got redefined back to my actual IP address (127.0.0.1) in between setting it to "37.35.128.128" and the console.log statement.

When I moved my code one step further into the callback chain, it worked as expected.

Is it possible that Node/Express has some internal mechanism that repeatedly sets `request.ip` to the user's actual IP address at runtime?

Comment: Yes, I would expect it to get set for each request.  On a multi-home/multi-interface box you could get different IPs for each request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The req.ip property in express is always pulled from the req.ips array via a function call, and it is built from the X-Forwarded-For header.

[Node.js: Get client's IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266329/node-js-get-clients-ip)

https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L285-L287

So when you ask for req.ip, it is always going to return the value from req.ips array. Aka, you cannot "set" the req.ip property. You need to instead use the request body, like `req.body.ip` if you need to do anything manual.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to spoof the ip address by fiddling around with core functionality of node / expressjs does not sound like the right approach. I would recommend you instead to enable `'trust proxy'` in your app, and then spoof the IP address by using `X-Forwarded-*` header. See [this](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#trust.proxy.options.table) for more details.

**EDIT:**

If you really want to `mock` the ip address of incoming requests, then might be worth looking at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mock-request). Again, I don't think `node / expressjs` was designed to allow modification of `req.ip` for any purpose at all.

Comment: This is good info, but doesn't fully answer my question. I am curious why I cannot redefine `request.ip` temporarily for debugging purposes.