# How curl recognize where the request come from?

Tags: php, security, curl

I plan to send some data from server A to server B via `curl`. I'm a little worried about a situation that attackers (server C) is going to pretend to be server A:

```
A->B : Hello, I am server A;
C->B : Hello, I am server A;
```

How does server B know who is server A or which data is from server A?

I'm a newbie in PHP. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is your Goal? Why you want to send the Data? Maybe you should read about replication, clustering and load balancing (if i interpreted your goal correctly)

Comment: I just want to send some user data from PHP to nodejs server.

Comment: Then why it is tagged with php instead of nodejs? Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-using-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get client IP.

Just get server A IP address, and on server B, check that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` equals server A IP.

Though if server C is on the same subnetwork than server A, then it will have the same address.

In this case, you can have A sending a key to server B, and B to verify it.

For instance : `A ==== data='blabla' ==== key='654zd87zda32z1d68zad7' ===> B`

And on B side, check that key is equal to 654zd87zda32z1d68zad7. You can change this key periodically to raise security (and / or have a more complex key).

On node.js it's prettry straightforward as well, to get client IP (using express), use : `req.ip`.

Comment: I'm afraid that server C may know the IP address too. Is IP address verification secure enough? Do I need to send an ecrypted key instead?

Comment: You can do both for maximum security.
Though IP is supposed to be unique and one can't tamper its IP address (for instance, you can change your mac address).