# How to add a default value from a function to the model in Sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

this is my model

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        ip: {
            type: 'ip'
        },
        useragent: {
            type: 'text'
        },
        type: 'int'
        }
    }
};
```

So what I need is before the record is created I need the ip and the useragent to be filled automatically from the request that comes in

Is this feasible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a Sails [policy](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies) by setting some properties on `req.options`.  If you have a `User` model and are using the blueprint `create` route, then in your **config/policies** you'd have:

```
UserController: {
  create: 'setValues'
}
```

and in **api/policies/setValues.js**:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

  req.options.values = req.options.values || {};
  req.options.values.ip = <SET IP>;
  req.options.values.agent = <SET USER AGENT>;
  return next();

};
```

I don't remember the preferred way to get user IP, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-using-node-js) looks promising.  For user agent you can try `req.headers['user-agent']`.

If you're using a custom controller action rather than the blueprints, this will still work fine, you'll just need to merge the values passed with the request with `req.options.values`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do this with Lifecyclecallbacks (see: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Lifecyclecallbacks.html)

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  ip: {
   type: 'ip'
  },
  useragent: {
   type: 'text'
  },

 },

 // Lifecycle Callbacks
 beforeCreate: function (values, cb) {
  values.ip = <SET IP>
  values.useragent = <SET USER AGENT>
  cb();
 });
};
```

Comment: I specifically said "I need to get the values from the REQUEST. I do not want to fill the values manually