# Passing data to the default controllers in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I have a user model and a widget model.  I have a relationship setup between user and widgets.  I also have a policy defined for authentication, if the user is authenticated then I'm saving the user ID in the req.session.

The user is required on the widget:

```
attributes: {
user: {model: 'user', required: true}
}
```

is there some way to tell the WidgetController to use the user from the auth policy and still use all the default actions provided by blueprint?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a default value from a function to the model in Sailsjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029948/how-to-add-a-default-value-from-a-function-to-the-model-in-sailsjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @MrVinz writes in his answer, policies are a great way to accomplish this.  However, altering `req.body` or `req.query` isn't recommended, because you might want access to their original values.  Instead, you can use `req.options.values` to provide defaults for blueprint values.  For example, to default the `name` value to a logged-in user's name, you could create a policy similar to:

```
module.exports = function defaultNamePolicy (req, res, next) {

  // Make sure req.options.values is an object, and don't overwrite
  // values from prior policies
  req.options.values = req.options.values || {};

  // If there's a logged in user, default to using their name.      
  // Otherwise this will be undefined and will have no effect
  req.options.values.name = req.session.user && req.session.user.name

  return next();

}
```

The values in `req.options.values` are used as defaults for the request, so if `req.param('name')` exists, it will be used instead of `req.options.values.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is :) You can use a policy to achieve this :)

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
                            if(req.session.user){
                              //then it depends on your implementation but 
                              req.params["widget"].user=req.session.user
                              //cab be req.query["widget"] or req.body["widget"]
                              /*
                                 if(req.params["widget"]){
                                   req.params["widget"].user=req.session.user   
                                 }
                                 if(req.query["widget"]){
                                   req.query ["widget].user=req.session.user
                                 }
                                 if(req.body["widget"]){
                                    req.body ["widget].user=req.session.user
                                 }
                              */
                            }
                            //other stuff
                            next();
                 }
```

you can also make this more generic by doing something like this

```
var model = req.options.model || req.options.controller;
if(model && sails.models[model].attributes['user']){
     //do the same trick
}
```

if you store a "user" full object in your `session` adapt the code and use a `req.session.user.id`

**EDIT**

My apologies i use custom blueprints and queries as i'am using sails ember blueprints :) however it makes things even easier you just have to check `req.params["user"]` or `req.query["user"]` if my memory is correct :)

Comment: You *cannot* alter `req.params` in a policy.  The original `params` object is re-applied to every middleware in the chain, so any changes you make in a policy won't be persisted to any controller action (or blueprint) that follows it.

Comment: @sgress454 good to know about options will have to change a bit my code.

Comment: @sgress454 btw can you provide any documentation reference to this statement i checked the ExpressJs API and sails doc on req and policies and i didn't find any statement about this

Comment: Yeah, it should be on [this page](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/req) right between `req.method` and `req.param()`, but clearly it's not there.  We'll get that added.  There was [already a question about this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029948/how-to-add-a-default-value-from-a-function-to-the-model-in-sailsjs), though...

Comment: @sgress454 thanks for you clarification, but i would prioritize the `req.options` documentation (as there is no doc on this same page...) and about req.param well [there is another question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801661/modify-node-js-req-object-parameters) and an [open issue on git ...](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1977) even if you closed [another one](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1667) i've already voted up your answer hope it will get to a high rank ... so that it's become a reference ...