# How do I get this guy's IP address in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Some dude is running some exploit scanner on my server. I'm getting weird requests like:

```
IP ADDRESS: ::ffff:127.0.0.1
www-0 (out): POST /cgi-bin/php5?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%22%79%65%73%22+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%69%78%5F%70%61%74%68%69%6E%66%6F%3D%31+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E
```

The IP is showing 127.0.0.1 using this code from [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524949/1048572):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log('IP ADDRESS: ', ip);
    next();
});
```

Looking to block this person on Cloudflare so it won't clutter my logs.

I'm running this on a Mac Mini server, it was freshly installed a couple of weeks ago, so I don't think my server has been compromised (or has it?) and running exploit scans locally.

Comment: Here is his request decrypted. `-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d cgi.redirect_status_env="yes" -d cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n `

Comment: `x-forwarded-for` is a header everybody can just set to anything and is useless for what you are trying to do. I would go as far as saying trying to track down random scanner / skiddy / freedom cyberfighter of some country on the east is useless and not worth your effort

Comment: what about the others: req.connection.remoteAddress and etc...? I guess I'll try removing the headers way and see what others provide.

Comment: Are you running nginx or a similar proxy in front of your node server?  If so, that's the thing terminating the internet connection from the outside.

Comment: I am running nginx in front. What do you mean terminating the internet connection from the outside?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `req.connection.remoteAddress` to get the *real* IP address of the person (or their proxy, which is what they need to make the request) and then you can store the different banned IPs in an array.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    if (bannedips.indexof(ip) > -1) {
        req.abort();
    }
    console.log("IP ADDRESS: ", ip);
    next();
});
```

---

EDIT

Now that I know you're using CloudFlare, the `CF-Connecting-IP` header would be more applicable to your situation.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var ip = req.headers["CF-Connecting-IP"];
    if (bannedips.indexof(ip) > -1) {
        req.abort();
    }
    console.log("IP ADDRESS: ", ip);
    next();
});
```

Comment: `req.connection.remoteAddress` is showing my remote test call as: `::ffff:127.0.0.1`. I am not making the call locally, so it should show my external IP address.

Comment: You said you're using Cloudflare? I'm not familiar with the platform, but I feel like that could be the issue. Cloudflare is getting all of the raw requests and is passing them on second hand to Node.js.

Comment: I found a Node.js module that can get the Cloudflare IP address for you. https://github.com/keverw/node_CloudFlare Try this out to see if it works.

Comment: i have cloudflare caching disabled. i can see my remote IP address when i make a request, just not this dude that's scanning my server

Comment: Using what method can you obtain your remote IP address through Cloudflare? The one above or in my answer?

Comment: Cloudflare passes the IP address of the person who makes a request through the `x-forwarded-for` header, but that can also be spoofed, so you'll need a new method for obtaining the correct IP.

Comment: my original code (from another StackOverflow answer) is able to detect normal remote IP addresses.

Comment: @Ninja Yes, because Cloudflare purposefully passes the IP over that header if there is no header there already. This won't work for people who spoof that header. You need to try another option.

Comment: so it's not possible to do this in node.js?

Comment: Did you try using the node_CloudFlare module?

Comment: Read this article by CloudFlare. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170986-How-does-CloudFlare-handle-HTTP-Request-headers- Try using the `CF-Connecting-IP` header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77057/discussion-between-dylanweber-and-ninja).

Comment: ok so it looks like there's no way to do this. i think the "hacker" is connecting directly to the IP. i'll have to resort to the logs of nginx.

Comment: You need to specify these things... you're using nginx?! That changes everything.

Comment: preferrably i don't want to modify nginx. the node.js app may be behind an apache proxy later. but it looks like that answer might help for now.