# how get ip client using express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get the client's IP and I 'm trying with localhost `(127.0.0.1 )` but I always get `:: 1`

i 'm trying using

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.send(req.ip); //I always get :: 1
 // or
 var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    res.send(ip);//I always get :: 1
});
```

how can get `127.0.0.1` and not `:: 1` . this can be done?

Comment: `::1` is your IPv6 address.

Comment: mmm ok but .. how can get IPv4? thx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`::1` is the IPv6 equivalent of `localhost`. If you want to only have your server listen over IPv4 and thus only have IPv4 addresses come in from your clients, you can specify an IPv4 address in `app.listen()`:

```
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting the clients IP address is pretty straightforward in NodeJS:

```
 var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
 console.log(ip);
```

Comment: Beware! This doesn't answer the question and `x-forwarded-for` might lead you to spoofed results. Do NOT copy-paste until you have read over http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524949/2013580 and its comments.