# How to Get ip address of client using our website using node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to get IP address of clients system who is using my website through java script and failed.I didn't want to use third parties such as "https://jsonip.com/" 
to retrieve this information.I know it is possible with Node.js and tried it but failed since this code it is not running.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
app.post('/testurl', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'm some random dude asking the same question 4 years later.. RESPEC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a part of the request

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
```

you can get it like this

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('your IP is: ' + req.connection.remoteAddress);
});

app.listen(1337);
```

Comment: I am getting "your IP is: ::1" as responce.but ip must be like example 192.168.23.78 right.can you help me.

Comment: yeah.. thats because you're running your app from localhost and testing it from the same machine. Try to access it over LAN or push your code to an external webserver and you'll see the IP changes. tl;dr; ::1 === IPv6 of localhost

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: apparently the req.connection is now deprecated in node v16.x.x, use req.socket instead

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen Good day, i am hosting on onrender and i have my IP displayed as "::1". what do you advise?

Comment: ::1 is IPv6 for Localhost. Try the API from another computer

Answer (score 2):

`::1` is IPv6 of localhost.

If you are only willing to listen to IPv4, use:

```
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30463191/2013580