# Is there a way to get private IPs using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, local, ips

I am going to make a console interface and it would connect to my virtual machine. However, I would want to find out who's connected on my local network so is there a way to get the client's local IP using pure JavaScript and no third party libraries? I have tried other methods like WebRTC but they don't seem to work anymore. PHP is also fine, but I would need to transfer the variable to the JavaScript.

Comment: Possible dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194722/can-you-get-a-users-local-lan-ip-address-via-javascript

Comment: I've seen that and have tried but that's the problem.. in chrome you have disable some extension. I'm looking for a way to get around that.

Comment: once your on the serving side, the following answer should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846540/how-to-get-ip-address-of-client-using-our-website-using-nodejs