# Get the ip address of the client making the request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have an application deployed on Azure and I'm trying to get the ip address of the remote client. Unfortunately I get always a value undefined when try to call

```
req.ip
```

Do you have any idea to get the ip address?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-using-node-js

Comment: Agreed, duplicate. A hint for the future, if you can find it in express, look at the node module references, express just wraps around the request and response objects.

Comment: @RahatMahbub - For those that agree its a dup, please vote to close it as a dup.

Answer (score 1):

```
const remoteAddress = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

Comment: can you provide some explanation about what you did and why?