# Loopback get IP address from operation hook

Tags: ip, hook, operation, loopback

Well, that XD, how do I get the IP Address of the querier (if that's even the word xD) from within an operation hook? or a remote hook? (I can save it with `loopback.getCurrentContext()` to use on the operation hook).

Say:

```
Model.observe('loaded', function(ctx,next) {
   ctx.ip ??
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I found this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1495 & this: [How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)
Great help from both, I just took what I needed to get the address and save it on the loopback current context like this on a startup script:

```
var loopback = require('loopback'); 

module.exports = function (app) {     

  app.remotes().before('*.*', function(ctx,next) {
    loopback.getCurrentContext().set('remoteAddress',ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress);
    next();
  });

  app.remotes().before('*.prototype.*', function(ctx,instance,next) {
    loopback.getCurrentContext().set('remoteAddress',ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress);
    next();
  });
};
```

Then I just get it on an operation hook like this:

```
Model.observe('loaded', function(ctx,next) {
   console.log("Remote Address: ", loopback.getCurrentContext().get('remoteAddress'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! So far it's the only solution I have found that works.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Loopback 3: you can get IP address using this property:

```
ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also add this code in server.js to grant the real ip, otherwise you´re getting the load balancer IP:

`app.set('trust proxy', ['loopback', 'linklocal', 'uniquelocal']);`

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

Not really the question asked, but when you need the ip address from the caller in a remote method, and your nodejs is already behind an Apache proxy (or a well configured nginx one), you can simply

```
    const ip = req.header('X-Forwarded-For')
```

to get the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP address of the requested user by using the below command.

```
var ipAddress = context.req.connection.remoteAddress
```