# How to get client IP in 3-tier architecture?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, x-forwarded-for

I am currently working on module which has the following architecture:

When a client makes a request it is forwarded to a node server which has a ELB in front of it. The node server gets the data from backend .NET code hosted in another server with a different call.

Is it possible to access the client IP in the backend code written in .NET considering this architecture?

Answer (score 0):

you can get ip in node

In your request object there is a property called connection, which is a net.Socket object. The net.Socket object has a property remoteAddress but it may be  possible ip server is behind proxy server so try the below code to get IP

```
request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

Check the below Stack Link for more answers

[How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)