# NodeJS REST Api - How to limit access by ip to specific endpoints?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I have a REST Api developed using MEAN stack. Everything works fine but now I need to limit the access to specific endpoints to specific IP addresses.
For example, I have the following endpoints:

```
/api/balance
/api/account
/api/register
/api/user/details //<-- this one I want to limit access only by ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (or list of ips)
```

My first thought is to create a middleware to intercept all requests, check if the endpoint access is limited and the origin IP and decide what to do.

There's a better solution or a proper way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node

Comment: Sounds perfectly valid approach to me. The other option would be having a layer in front of your web app e.g. firewall, which avoids having to embed network security in your app.