# Setup a server that can detect IP addresses of clients

Tags: server, ip-address, webservice-client

I am trying to set up what is possibly a webserver that can detect the IP addresses of the clients that try to access the webpage. In the simplest terms.

1)Let there be a table on the website.

2)Each time a client requests the website, its IP address gets added to the entry of the table.

I have made a webserver before using apache tomcat and even nodejs. But I have no idea how to detect IP adresses. I would also like to know if its possible to set this up online, in the cheapest possible way.

Comment: By table, do you mean a database, or an actual table on your website that displays the ip addresses of visitors?

Comment: Refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps nodejs would work using `request.connection.remoteAddress`, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node).