# Not able to get client IP address on server in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am working on nodeJS project in this project I want to get client IP address. For this I am using public IP package, I’m using
the following code, and installed the package accordingly.

```
‘npm install --save public-ip
```

and following code

```
publicIp.v4().then(ip => {

});’
```

The above code is working fine locally, but when deployed on the server(AWS server), it’s giving the AWS server IP.
Help me resolve the issue.

Comment: request.connection.remoteAddress?

Comment: @NitinDhomse I tried this but not working on server

Comment: @kushalpawar are you sure you're using the correct tool here, this package will give you the _server_'s IP address. Are you looking for the _connecting client_ IP address?

Comment: @James I need client machine IP address, above code work fine locally , but not working on server. is there any configuration needed on server for this?

Comment: This is for sure not the right tool for getting the **client's** IP address. Description of the package: *Get **your** public IP address - very fast!*

Comment: are you using https?

Comment: @kushalpawar *"work fine locally"* most likely because the you'll be testing on the same machine you're running the server.... You need to inspect the incoming web request for the client IP (as per the example from Nitin Dhomse)

Comment: @loulala yes i am using http

Comment: @James  nodejs API called from mobile app , and i am getting correct ip of mobile,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)

Comment: @kushalpawar let me guess, mobile app either running locally on an emulator or running off the same wifi network?

Comment: @James we have tested with mobile app using mobile own data ,

Comment: @kushalpawar How is the mobile app able to access your local machine?