# how to get the ip address in node js

Tags: node.js, http, npm, ip

I'm trying to get users IP addreses in node but it always return local IP, I used different packages like ipware, request-ip but result is the same. How can I get real IPs
this is my code now

```
var requestIp = require('request-ip');
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    ip = requestIp.getClientIp(req);
    next();
});
```

Comment: Have you read this [how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node), you can also go with nodejs own methods

Comment: What is the actual IP though? Isnt it localhost if your server is on your local machine?

Comment: @cowCrazy  yes I tryed this all methodes, but no result, can't imagine what is the problem

Comment: no my server is not on my local machine @SelloMkantjwa

Comment: @Mona oh ok. I see

Comment: Is the server sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: Is there a proxy in front of your server?  Or is the client connecting directly to your server with no load balancer or proxy?

Comment: Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node

Comment: I'm running server behind a proxy @SelloMkantjwa

Comment: yes there is a proxy @jfriend00

Comment: If you're running a proxy, then the connection your server sees is from the proxy, not from the client.  You can ONLY know what the client IP is if the proxy adds the client IP address to a header so you can get it from there.  You will have to consult your proxy documentation to find out if it already does that or if it can be configured to do so.  For example, here's info about that for NGINX: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105418/getting-ip-address-and-location-of-my-own-server-instead-of-visiting-users