# How to get client public ip from api request in node js ?

Tags: node.js

Is there any possible way to get client public ip from api request in node js ?

From request we can get only local ip ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)

Answer (score 1):

In nodejs http callback:

`request.socket.remoteAddress`

if you have a load balancer environment:

`(req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || '').split(',')[0] || req.socket.remoteAddress`

Comment: Update: Connection is deprecated. Use request.socket.remoteAddress instead
 https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress