# I need to know where user came from node js

Tags: node.js

I have a back-end by nodejs I need to know where user come from. 
if he came from localhost (postman) or his website HTTP request.
I need to know his user domain's not mind like 'http://localhost/' or 'http://user-website.com' or even from google search ! from he is came ?

, I tried user `req.get('origin)` but always return undefined

Answer (score 1):

You must connect 'url' module

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url') ;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var hostname = req.headers.host; // hostname = 'localhost:8080'
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname; // pathname = '/MyApp'
  console.log('http://' + hostname + pathname);

  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but i need to know where user came from , like if he access from post man or his website from http request

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo: ah, looks like you need to use headers "User-Agent" and "Referer". Look them up.

Comment: This does not answers the OP's question. This gives the hostname of the machine the server is running on, not the client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

use `req.headers['user-agent']` to see if it is postman agent or not.

Comment: it's give me a browser "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"

Answer (score 0):

In order to know whether the request is coming from `localhost` or a remote client, you'll need to obtain the client's IP address. Example in Express:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const ipAddress = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  // ...
});
```

More docs about getting the IP [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/http.html#http_response_socket), also check [this other question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node).

Basically if the request is coming from `localhost`, `ipAddress` will be `::1` or other [localhost IP address](https://whatismyipaddress.com/localhost), but if it's not, it's going to look like a public IP address, like `173.194.79.101` (the IP of google.com).

Comment: thanks but it's give that "::ffff:169.254.8.129" to me from localhost and postman ! isn't there any way or third part package give me a domain name  ?

Comment: I found this solution req.header('Referer') this give to ma the previous page is this is best answer ?

Comment: No, referer can be spoofed, and it's an optional field. it's a bad idea to use if

Comment: You can use [dns.reverse](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback) to resolve the IP address to a hostname

Comment: I'm trying dns.reverse but it's always give to me `{"errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getHostByAddr","hostname":"::ffff:169.254.8.129"}`

Comment: That's valid behavior. You should only reverse-DNS `69.254.8.129`. It should point to `c-69-254-8-129.hsd1.ga.comcast.net.`.

Comment: By the way, you should handle cases where reverse DNS resolution doesn't find any hostname - every hostname has an IP, but not every IP is linked with a hostname! The [wikipedia page for DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) can be helpful to understand why.