# How to get ip from request nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get ip from a post request.

```
var ip = req.ip || req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
req.connection.remoteAddress || 
req.socket.remoteAddress ||
(req.connection.socket ? req.connection.socket.remoteAddress : null)

res.json({
  success: true,
  message: 'ip'+ip
});
```

but it returns a `null` value. I'm using on a serve(it isn't a localhost)

Is there any solution?
all solutions returns `null`;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)

Comment: @Andrey all solutions returns a `null` value.

Comment: It doesn't mean question isn't a dublicate. There's multiple headers possible holding IP address. This package for example checks much more, you can try it: https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip/blob/master/src/index.js

Comment: @Andrey `request-ip` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's behind a reverse proxy like Nginx try using the the embedded variables from ngx_http_core_module. (At least that's what I'm doing years now).

Nginx configuration file

```
....
location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
....
```

Node.js

```
req.headers["x-real-ip"]
```