# NodeJS trigger "when some visitor enter the website"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to console log when a visitor's IP address when visits the homepage but can't trigger GET.

Here is my code:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var userIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(userIP + " connected to the site.");
});
```

There is no console log when I enter the website.

Comment: where do you expect the log to show up, on the client or on the server? What does java have to do with it?

Comment: Do you mean to say, the `console.log...` itself is not getting executed (or else) you are not getting the `userIP` alone?

Comment: I expect the log show up on the server and yes console.log not getting executed.

Comment: may be this call help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node

Comment: Can you please post the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const express = require("express")

function visitor (req, res, next) {
   console.log(req.ip)
   console.log(req.path)
   console.log(req.method)

   next();
}


const app = express();

app.use(visitor);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var userIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(userIP + " connected to the site.");
});
```