# How can i get user id serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, user-management

I am making a node.js application with express and i need to get user ID. I need something like "req.userID", to use like that:

```
var counter=0;
var user = new Array();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
 var aux=0;
 user.forEach(i => { 
  if(i != req.userID)
   var aux++;
  else console.log("User exist!");
  if(aux === user.length)
   user.push(req.userID);
 })

});
```

Comment: You will need an authentication middleware to attach the user credentials to the request.

Comment: What is "userID"? Do you mean some kind of account ID? If so, look up Cookies.

Comment: Can you explain about the issue a bit more?

Comment: @technicallynick I'm a newbie to node.js, can you explain a little more?

Comment: @ObsoleteAwareProduce No, i want userID to be something **like** user network IP.

Comment: To get IP, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node). BTW, middleware is a function that sits between express and your code, usually helping out with something like POST data parsing or authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"req.connection.remoteAddress"
Thanks ObsoleteAwareProduce, that's exactly what i was looking for :D