# Find the clients' IP address using an ExpressJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, user-agent

A few days ago, I wrote a [nodejs script](https://repl.it/@HackaTunes/simplehttpserver) to log user agents. While my script did work, I could not a find a working way to log the `REMOTE_ADDRESS` of the client.

***app.js:***

```
var express = require('express'), http = require('http'), app = express();

http.createServer(app).listen(8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.get('user-agent')))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.get('user-agent')));
});
```

So, if you `curl http://localhost:8080` it returns `curl/7.55.1`.

However, I could not achieve to log the IP address of the client.
Any solutions to it?

Comment: Did you look at [`req.ip`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ip) and [`req.ips`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.ips).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.connection.remoteAddress` use this. If your request comes from localhost, IP will be shown as `::1` But if your request comes from different IP, then it will show correct IP. If you want to consider request coming from proxy servers also, take a look at this code:
[IP Address Code Snippet](https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/remoteAddress?snippet=5f67c35d4b42a09e18721145)

Comment: Hi, is there some way to just get ipv4 addresses from the same? When the app is requested from something like a mobile network an ipv6 address is returned, as expected.

Comment: It is not good practice to convert IPv6 to IPv4. But if you want to convert it to IPv4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node this question have some answers. But there is no guarantee that converted IPv4 will be the correct equivalent of IPv6.