# How to retrieve machine IP address of user based on API request in node JS?

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to get an user machine IP address when he/she made a call to my API in node.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a user's IP address in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107856/how-to-determine-a-users-ip-address-in-node)